# Collapse android when I try to close keyboard

Tags: java, android

this is my layouts XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/sifreunuttum"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GirisEkrani">
```

, and my onCreat method

```
    findViewById(R.id.sifreunuttum).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

in layout there are 2 EditText and a button, I am trying to close the keyboard when touching screen. It works only if clicking the EditText first then when you click screen keyboard is closing. But if you start the activity and try to touching the screen first the app collapse. How i can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide your activity when using getSystemService()!

```
Activity activity = YourActivity.this
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```